# Error while creating a new thrift connection to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, kairosdb

I am trying to setup a KairosDB installation using Cassandra as backend, but I am facing  the following error:

[HThriftClient.java:152] - Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
 ERROR [HConnectionManager.java:418] - MARK HOST AS DOWN TRIGGERED for host localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
 ERROR [HConnectionManager.java:422] - Pool state on shutdown: :{localhost(127.0.0.1):9042}; IsActive?: true; Active: 1; Blocked: 0; Idle: 15; NumBeforeExhausted: 49

[HConnectionManager.java:303] - Exception: 
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorTransportException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:39) ~[hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]

I already checked the cassandra opened port and it is set to 9042. Also, I set start_rpc to true on cassandra.yaml file. Any idea on further troubleshooting?

Comment: Make sure no firewall is blocking your ports. Which IP/interface are you binding Cassandra to (`rpc_address` or `rpc_interface` in cassandra.yaml)?

Comment: Using Thrift to connect to Cassandra is deprecated, and Hector hasn't processed a pull request in almost 2 years.  In fact, Hector's main page even tells you not to use it anymore.  Switch over to the DataStax Java driver, and you'll be a lot happier.

Answer (score 0):

For thrift connection cassandra use 9160 port . so give 9160 port .

Comment: I am facing now the following error after gave 9160 port. Any idea?DEBUG [HThriftClient.java:183] - Unable to open transport to localhost(127.0.0.1):9160
11:08:44.083 [main] ERROR [HConnectionManager.java:71] - Could not start connection pool for host localhost(127.0.0.1):9160
11:08:44.083 [main] INFO  [CassandraHostRetryService.java:68] - Host detected as down was added to retry queue: localhost(127.0.0.1):9160
11:08:44.084 [Hector.me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService-1] DEBUG [HThriftClient.java:152] - Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9160

Comment: off firewall on your system

Answer (score 0):

What version of Cassandra are you using?

I think thrift is disabled in newer versions of Cassandra, you may enable the protocol by modifying Cassandra.yaml and restarting cassandra (or maybe by using nodetool).